# Odoo 10 - How to hide a One2many field

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, one2many

I have a `One2many` field, and against the attrs I want to put something along the lines of - if this `One2many` is blank then hide it.

The `One2many` is already auto populated from other objects, so all I need to do is set the invisible to something like...

```
{'invisible':[('this_field_ids','=',False)]}
```

There is only one problem... this does not work for a `One2many` field.

If it was a `boolean`, `char`, or `Many2one` then it would work, but the `One2many` acts differently.

What can I put in the attrs to make this (or in this case, the 'page' that this is within) invisible if it is empty?

I believe that I can make a separate computed field to get the job done, but I wanted to know if I can achieve this without the computed field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comparaison should be with an empty list:

```
{'invisible':[('this_field_ids', '=', [])]}
```

Answer (score 3):

To hide One2many field, use this condition inside attrs attribute as follows..

```
attrs="{'invisible': [('this_field_ids', '=', [(6, False, [])])]}"
```